# TableRowSorter shows different result everytime I clicked searchButton

Tags: java, rowfilter, tablerowsorter

For my code, I had a really weird bug.
Everytime I press the Search Button, the result always different.

This is my dummy database.

I have 4 columns and 3 rows in the table :

```
001 Viagra 1 APL
002 Diane 2 SBF
003 Santibi 3 BSP
```

The first time I pressed the Search Button, the data inside table didn't change at all.

This is the screenshot of my program.
This is what happened if I pressed the Search Button the second time (the result is correct)

[image: This is what happened if I pressed the Search Button the second time (the result is correct)]

The third time I pressed the button, it shows an incorrect result

[image: The third time I pressed the button, it shows an incorrect result]

If I pressed the button continuously, the result keep changing back and fort from correct to incorrect one.

This is my code :`

```
public void searchPerformed() {
    if (tSearch.getText().toString() == sch) { return; }
    sch = tSearch.getText().toString();

    int iColumn = cbSearch.getSelectedIndex();

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
    tbl.setRowSorter(sorter);

    if (tSearch.getText().length() > 0) {
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + tSearch.getText(), iColumn));

    } else {
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
    }

    if (tbl.getRowCount() != 0) { tbl.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0); }
    else { clearText(); }

}

private void tSearchKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    if (evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) { return; }

    searchPerformed();
}     

private void tSearchKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    if (evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) { return; }

    searchPerformed();
}
```